# Using UWP CalendarDatePicker results in Windows.Foundation.IReference`1 <Windows.Foundation.DateTime>

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp

This may be stupid, as I am just learning UWP and figured I'd try making a tool that uses CalendarDatePicker, however I cannot get it to display the date entered in the box.

XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="dateOutput"/>
<CalendarDatePicker x:Name="OrderDate" DateChanged="ChangeOrderDate"/>
```

C++

```
void OrderService::MainPage::ChangeOrderDate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::CalendarDatePicker^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::CalendarDatePickerDateChangedEventArgs^ args)
{

dateOutput->Text = OrderDate->Date->Value.ToString();

}
```

When I run this code, I can select a date but what displays is the following:

> Windows.Foundation.IReference`1  Windows.Foundation.DateTime>

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot replicate this in my C# UWP project.

Answer (score 1):

What is actually being shown on the Textblock it's the `DateTime.Value.ValueType`, rather than the actual value of DateTime.Value.

[`Windows.Foundation.IReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.ireference_t_) is an hidden interface, which appears as `Nullable<T>` in .NET and as `Platform::IBox` in C++/CX, and `.Value` property that you are trying to access, is part of the implementation of this same interface.

> The ValueType::ToString method overrides the Object::ToString method
>   and provides the default implementation of the ToString method for
>   value types. (Value types are types defined by the struct keyword in
>   C#

DateTime is a value type, and that's why ::ToString() is being overriden by ValueType::ToString

Can you try to overload the toString, also including an argument indicating what is the desired format output for your Date value, like "dddd dd MMMM" ?

Comment: I actually did try overloading it, and ended up getting "'Platform::ValueType::ToString': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments"

Answer (score 0):

For the `DateTime` value of the [`CalendarDatePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker),  C++/CX uses the [`Windows::Foundation::DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.datetime) structure. Details please reference [DateTime and Calendar values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/date-and-time#datetime-and-calendar-values).
Directly invoking `ToString()` will return the type, for reason you could check @André B's reply.

We may need to get the `DateTime.UniversalTime` value to convert according to the Remarks of DateTime Structure:

> To convert the UniversalTime to SYSTEMTIME, use ULARGE_INTEGER to convert the int64 value to FILETIME, then use FileTimeToSystemTime to get SYSTEMTIME.

But you could just use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter) class in UWP app to format your `DataTime` for display. Details for how to do please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-patterns-to-format-dates-and-times) and [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DateTimeFormatting/cpp). For example:

```
void CCalendar::MainPage::ChangeOrderDate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::CalendarDatePicker^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::CalendarDatePickerDateChangedEventArgs^ args)
{ 
    DateTime current = OrderDate->Date->Value; 
    Array<DateTimeFormatter^> ^dateFormatters = {
        ref new DateTimeFormatter("shortdate"),
        ref new DateTimeFormatter("longdate"),
        ref new DateTimeFormatter("shorttime"),
        ref new DateTimeFormatter("longtime")
    };
    String^ results = ""; 
    // Generate the results.
    for (auto formatter : dateFormatters)
    {
        // Perform the actual formatting. 
        results = results + formatter->Template + ": " + formatter->Format(current) + "\n";
    }
    dateOutput->Text = results;  
}
```